# Folding hash vs Masking

Tags: hash

If I want an 8-bit hash, for the purpose of searching, is it better to fold a larger hash (e.g. 128 bits) or a simple masking / assignment will do?

In addition, if I need a number that is not zero to a power of 2 (say, 0-25). Are there any concern of using mod() operation?